# Ho to use Multiple instance of a tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat6

I have **two** **Servlet** and i want to run both **Servlet** on the same time on same server(tomcat6) through multiple instance of a server on different port in Windows is there any options through i can do this. waiting for your response
Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need to run them on separate servers? you have *two* servlets mapped with different *URLs* so you could just call them simultaneously

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794444/use-multiple-catalina-base-to-setup-tomcat-6-instances-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not described what is preventing you from doing what you want to do?

Just run the two tomcat instances and request the two servlets at the same time. There will be a small time-lag between the two requests if you do it manually (using a browser), so if you want to avoid it then you can use something like HttpUnit to programmatically fire the request.

Comment: to run multiple tomcat servers from the same installation see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794444/use-multiple-catalina-base-to-setup-tomcat-6-instances-on-windows