# Running multiple instances of Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

I'm trying to get multiple instances of tomcat 7 running on the same server. However, it doesn't seem to be working

I've set the new instance to be on port 8180

CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.35"
CATALINA_BASE="/srv/tomcat/spock"
export CATALINA_HOME CATALINA_BASE

$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start

When I go:

wget localhost:8180

It fails, which means that the service didn't start properly.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do they have separate catalina_base locations. This is required.

Comment: Yes. I have one as /srv/tomcat/spock and one as /srv/tomcat/redshirt.  But starting the script doesnt work

Comment: [How to setup multiple instances of tomcat][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794444/use-multiple-catalina-base-to-setup-tomcat-6-instances-on-windows