# running multiple instance of tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to install tomcat 7 in my wondows system. I have tomcat 6.0.35 installed and it is working. But I'm unable to install tomcat 7.

I have chaned the port numbers.

For tomcat 6.0.35,

```
Server port="8105" , Connector port="8181", AJP 1.3 port="8109"
```

this is working(at localhost 8181).

For tomcat 7.0.23

```
Server port="8106" , Connector port="8182", AJP 1.3 port="8110"
```

tomcat 7 is not running, the startup.bat file is running, but the tomcat home page is not showing in browser.

here is the log

```
Feb 19, 2014 4:21:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component      [StandardServer[8106]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:624)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)   
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat multiple instances simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110528/tomcat-multiple-instances-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

The below link helps in configuring this:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt