# I need to run Pentaho CE BI-Server and Geoserver in the same Tomcat 7 on my server

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, pentaho, geoserver

The thing is that I have running GeoServer on a Tomcat 7 instance on my server. I had to install Pentaho BI-Server for data warehouse, but i start the service of Pentaho and immediately GeoServer Services stoped.

I start to wonder what's went wrong and I found that the download of Pentaho has own Tomcat Server. So thats was the problem the tomcat server from pentaho starts and took the ports of Tomcat that was running.

My question is how to configure the two tomcat to work together.

Thanks to all.

Comment: You can change port of GeoServer from default 8080 to something else in server.xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply KNOWARTH, how is gona affect to GeoServer functions if I change the ports?

Comment: It won't affect GeoServer functions.

Comment: Hi KNOWARTH, try what you suggested, but instead of changing the ports of geoserver have changed pentaho. While running geoserver start the pentaho server and this shot down geoserver. Finish pentaho service and geoserver returned to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution gave KNOWARTH is correct, I also guide me the next post to know what ports need to change:

[Link where is show what port to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110528/tomcat-multiple-instances-simultaneously)

Greats to all.