# Windows Tomcat properly shut down

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, shutdown

I have an application that starts tomcat with an hidden command line (like startup.bat), when I shut down Windows tomcat process is not closed propery but simply killed. I can feel it because is not call the ContextDestroy method of my web application. By other hand if I call tomcat shutdown.bat the method is called.
Is there any way to let windows close correctly tomcat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat multiple instances simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110528/tomcat-multiple-instances-simultaneously)

Comment: Possibile duplicate? I'm speaking of properly of tomcat shutdown during Windows shutdown. Not how to run many instances!