# Multiple Tomcat sessions on Windows Server

Tags: windows, tomcat, tomcat7

I've been asked to put together a Tomcat webserver on a Windows server that can host numerous instances of an application for our development, UAT, training and sandboxes systems.  We had them all running on one instance of Tomcat 7 however that was causing the application to crash due to the number of them running and made it hard to update just one environment without bringing them all down.  These sites are all internal use only and not public facing so we are using short DNS names to reach the sites.

What I am planning to do now is have multiple sessions that are started using batch files which is working apart from the fact that to reach the sites I have use the full IP, port number and directory name.  If I try to access the sites using the short name it displays the main Tomcat sessions default page (running on port 80).

What I am hoping to do is have it so when we use the short name it redirects to the correct session (example below using 127.0.0.1 as an example IP address)

- Typing site1 should redirect to 127.0.0.1:8081/site1
- Typing site2 should redirect to 127.0.0.1:8081/site2
- Typing site3 should redirect to 127.0.0.1:8082/site3

Comment: Here is a nice article answering exactly your question: http://www.ansoncheunghk.info/article/5-steps-install-multiple-apache-tomcat-instance-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat multiple instances simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110528/tomcat-multiple-instances-simultaneously)